# Auto cursor not applied in Gecko

Tags: css, cursor, gxt, gecko

*This seems like a rendering engine quirk, as it had been tested and failed to reproduce on WebKit driven browsers (Chrome and Safari for Windows).*

### Description

When using a deep nested DOM structure, such as the GXT `Grid`, the `default` cursor seem to override any other style applied. How to override (or sidestep) this behavior?

### Test Case

#### Steps To Reproduce

*(Requires basic knowledge of your favored browser's developer tools)*

1. Visit the [GXT 2.2.x examples showcase](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#basicgrid).
2. Right-click a cell text value in the grid and click *Inspect Element*, or hit `F12` to open the developer tools and than inspect that element manually. You should be inspecting an element notated as: `div.x-grid3-cell-inner.x-grid3-col-name`.
3. In the *Styles* view, look for a rule matching the following selector: `.x-grid3-row`, it should have a single declared property for `cursor`. Change its value from `default` to `auto`.

#### Expected Result

The cursor should be rendered according to the element's type, e.g. text cursor for text content elements.

#### Actual Result

On Gecko based browsers, the default cursor appears regardless of the element's type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue caused by ancestor elements with a declared `tabindex` attribute with a value equals or larger than `0`, and is a [reported bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=389283) in the Mozilla bug tracker.

It can be reproduced by running [this simple test case](https://bug389283.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=273429) on Gecko browsers (run on WebKit for a reference).

As a workaround, one can ensure all elements up the hierarchy are assigned with a `tabindex` value of `-1`, or remove those altogether, thus avoiding entering [this block](http://bonsai.mozilla.org/cvsblame.cgi?file=/mozilla/layout/generic/nsTextFrameThebes.cpp&rev=3.54&root=/cvsroot&mark=3439-3454#3431), turning cursor related CSS rules back to their normal behavior.